# Is there a way to fix this error in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

so every time I try building my project in Unity as a WebGL the same error always comes up. It says this:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

First, what does this mean, and second how can i fix this. 
Some additional info:
I am using Unity 2018.4
I have Mapbox as an asset or plugin or whatever you want to call it 
I need this by next week.
Also i don't know much about Unity so please try to keep this simple. Thank you so much!